# Keyset pagination with WHERE & HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pagination, having

I ran into a question that I can't find a solution yet for keyset pagination:

Suppose we have this query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.number, AVG(b.rating) AS rating 
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON xxxxxxx
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY rating DESC, a.number DESC
LIMIT xxxx
```

How should we do keyset pagination on that?

For a.number only, we can have 
`WHERE a.number < ?;`
For rating only, we do `HAVING rating < ?;`
If there're two conditions for where, we can have `WHERE (x, y) < (?, ?)`.

But how to do both HAVING and WHERE?

Edit:
I implemented this today and found out that it's slower than OFFSET pagination, so not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where you never can use, because it can'_t access rating.

What you can do is

> HAVING (x, y) < (1, 1)

```
SELECT a.id, a.number, AVG(b.rating) AS rating 
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.number
HAVING (a.number, rating) < (1, 1)
ORDER BY rating DESC, a.number DESC
LIMIT xxxx
```